# Unit testing template code

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, constraints, template-meta-programming

Imagine that I have a lot of template code that I can test with `static_assert`s, so for example

```
template <typename Help>
class SomeUtil { ... };

static_assert(std::is_same<SomeUtil<Type>::type, int>::value, "message");
```

Is the only way to test this by making a `main.cpp` that just includes this header and compiling it?  `-fsyntax-only` did not seem to work.

Comment: Well, I could think of ways like autotools do. Try to compile a specific piece of code and see if the compiler in action fails on it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i have a small script that does exactly that but somehow that is not making me happy..

Comment: What exactly is your concern? Would you mind to show us your current approach?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am looking for a native (when I say native I mean `gcc`, `clang` would do too I guess). Current approach is to have a bash function that checks the current working directory and makes a file with a random name, includes the header passed in as the argument, write a small main and compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact `gcc` and `clang` both can read `stdin`:

```
clang -c -o /dev/null -xc++ - <header.h
```

Step by step:

- `-c` - compile but not link
- `-o /dev/null` - do not produce any output files
- `-xc++` - source type would be C++
- `-` - source given as stdin
- `<header.h` - supply your header file as input

Note that you must also pass any relevant to your project `-D` or `-I` flags.

To fix warning about `#pragma once in main file`, you can either:

- Suppress it, if your compiler supports `-Wpragma-once-outside-header`
- Feed header indirectly with `echo`:

  `echo '#include "header.h"' | clang -c -o /dev/null -xc++ -`

Do not forget the trailing `-`.

Comment: `-o /dev/null` looks nice. I've been adopting that if you kindly allow ;-).

Comment: I upvoted your answer but seems like this makes the compiler think that this is the main file.  For example, when I do that with a template header file the output I get from `g++` is `warning: #pragma once in main file [enabled by default]`.  Any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, lest's assume you have a testing framework like gtest, I'd try to write a test like

```
TEST_F(MyTestClass,CheckSomeUtilCompiles) {
    std::string codeInQuestion = R"(
    #include "MyTemplate.h"
    int main() {
        // instantiate SomeUtil with some invalid condition:
        SomeUtil<int> x;
    }
    )";
    std::ofstream testFile("testcode.cpp");
    testfile << codeInQuestion;
    testfile.close();

    EXPECT_EQ(?,system("$CPP -c $CPPFLAGS testcode.cpp -o /dev/null"));
           // ^ Something other than zero
}
```

Comment: I’ve never tried it so maybe this works really well in practice but it seems rather brittle and overkill. I’d prefer having a testing harness in a shell scripting language that tries compiling code snippets. You’d have to write your own testing harness for that but it should be (*it is*, I’ve done it) very simple.

Comment: @KonradRudolph _"I’d prefer having a testing harness in a shell scripting language "_ Well,  I'm preferring to test such stuff within my regular unit tests.

Comment: Actually you've convinced me.